# Get SHA-256 certificate checksum for debug apk (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, keytool

I want to get SHA-256 certificate checksum for debug apk (Android).
I'm using this command `

```
keytool -printcert -jarfile path/to/my/app/debug-app.apk` | grep SHA256
```

However, it doesn't display anything. Why is that? What can be wrong?

Comment: Any luck? did you solve this?